# Looking for help in making my socket messenger send instantaneously in Python

Tags: python, sockets, command-line, distributed-system, messenger

Im sure there are easier ways with particular python modules, but for an assignment I need to create a program that can act as a client/server. As of right now I have it working to the point of only being able to send a message if the reciever has responded. I need it to just send and appear on the respective client/server terminal when enter is pressed. Any help would be greatly appreciated!

These are pictures of what happens as of now
https://i.stack.imgur.com/T9CsJ.png

```
import sys
import socket
import getopt

def usage(script_name):
    print('Usage: py' + script_name + '-l' +' <port number>' + '[<server>]')

def sockObj():
    sock = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
    return sock

def serversockConn(serversocket,port):
    serversocket.setsockopt(socket.SOL_SOCKET,socket.SO_REUSEADDR,1)
    # bind the serversocket to address
    serversocket.bind(('',int(port)))
    # enable a server to accept connections
    serversocket.listen(5)
    # wait for a connection and accept it
    sock,addr = serversocket.accept()
    return sock

def connToServersock(sock,server, port):
    # connect to a serversocket
    if server:
        sock.connect((server, int(port)))
    else:
        sock.connect(('localhost', int(port)))
    return sock

if __name__ == '__main__':
    ## get the command line arguments
    try:
        options, non_option_args = getopt.getopt(sys.argv[1:],'l')
    except getopt.GetoptError as err:
        print(err)
        sys.exit(2)

    #check if '-l' is present in command line agrument
    serverSide = False
    for opt,arg in options:
        if opt == "-l":
            serverSide = True

    # port number
    port = non_option_args[0]

    # server address
    server = None
    hostLen = len(non_option_args)
    if hostLen == 2:
        server = non_option_args[1]


    # create a communicator object, and make a connection between server and client

    # server
    if serverSide:
        serversocket = sockObj()
        sock = serversockConn(serversocket,port)
    # client
    else:
        sock = sockObj()
        sock = connToServersock(sock,server,port)

    while True:
        ## read a message from standard input
        message = sys.stdin.readline().encode()
        if len(message) != 0:
            sock.send(message)
            return_msg = sock.recv( 1024 )
            if return_msg:
                print("Message recieved: " + return_msg.decode())
            else:
                print("Other side shut down")
        else:
            try:
                sock.shutdown(socket.SHUT_WR)
                sock.close()
            except:
                pass
```

Answer (score 0):

I think your issue is that there are two places in your event loop where you block:

```
    message = sys.stdin.readline().encode()
```

Here, you block until the user has pressed return -- during this time, your program is unable to respond to any data received over the network, because it is blocked waiting for data from stdin.

... and:

```
        return_msg = sock.recv( 1024 )
```

Here, you are waiting for data to be received from the network -- during this time, your program is unable to respond to any data received from stdin, because it is blocked waiting for data from the network.

The behavior you'd ideally like to have is for your program to wait for both stdin and network traffic simultaneously -- i.e. have it block until either the user has pressed return, *or* some network data has been received, whichever comes first.

The easiest way to achieve that behavior is to use `select()`; its purpose is to block until at least one of several file descriptors is ready to be acted on.  (Note, however, that Windows does not support using `select()` on stdin, so if your program needs to run under Windows you will probably have to spawn a second thread instead).

To implement the event loop using `select()`, add `import select` to the top of your script, then replace your event loop with something like this instead:

```
while True:
    ## block here until either sock or sys.stdin has data ready for us
    readable, writable, exceptional = select.select([sock, sys.stdin], [], [])

    if sys.stdin in readable:
        ## read a message from standard input
        message = sys.stdin.readline().encode()
        if len(message) != 0:
            sock.send(message)

    if sock in readable:
        ## read a message from the network
        try:
            return_msg = sock.recv( 1024 )
            if (return_msg):
               print("Message received: " + return_msg.decode())
            else:
               print("Other side shut down")
               break
        except:
            print("recv() threw an exception")
            break
```

Comment: Thank you so much! I didn't realize I was blocking off access in the loop, this makes a lot more sense.